# Font-awesome icon is overlapping truncated text on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a link in my page that is formed by a text followed by a font-awesome icon. This link can not bypass a given width, so I created I css class to truncate the text if necessary. Also the icon need to be aligned to the right (I'm using `float:right`).

This is the fiddle with the example of what I'm trying to do:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czf552vp/3/)

and here is the code:

```
<div class="divclass truncate">
    <a href="www.google.com" title="blablablablabla">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-lock" style="float:right;" title="Read only"></i>
        blablablablablablablablabla
    </a>
</div>

.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.divclass {
    width: 100px;
}
```

This works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox the icon is overlapping the text.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d probably approach this in a slightly different way:

- apply `width` and `text-overflow` to the link itself
- position the icon absolutely
- give the link some extra padding to the right to make space for the icon

http://jsfiddle.net/czf552vp/7/

Comment: I was trying to figure out a solution, and I was already half-way on a position solution. ;)